# How can I add fields named Latitude and Longitude using GeoFire in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, geolocation, database-normalization, geofire

[image: Picture of the Database]

I'm developing a Location Tracking App with Android Studio and need to store coordinates in a normalized manner (One Variable in One Field). Can I modify the location data created by GeoFire in Firebase? I would like to have a single field called **Latitude** and another one called **Longitude**. In the picture above you can see that the coordinates are both stored below one field called ' **l** ', I would like to modify this, or copy them as separate childs of the current userID in the node **Location**. Would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Geofire is open-source, so you can modify it to use the property names you want. Just be aware that Geofire uses these shorter names to limit the bandwidth it uses, so your users see a bandwidth increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built into Geofire for you control the property names. But since Geofire is open-source, you can modify it to use the property names you want.

Just be aware that Geofire uses these shorter names to limit the bandwidth it uses, so your users see a bandwidth increase.

Comment: Thank you for your response Frank. I'm just looking to see if I can make the Database work with Firestation. My goal is to do nested queries and get the coordinates from the table LOCATION, but the latitude and longitude have to be just below the UserId leaf to work. They have to be a child, not a grandchild. I will check info on how to modify GeoFire. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to do your own queries, do them on your own object structure. In fact, I'd recommend two top-level lists: `Users` and `UserLocations`. The latter is completely managed by Geofire, and you just ignore what's in it (beyond what the Geofire API gives you). The latter is completely yours, and that's where you do your own queries. The overlap between the two is based on the keys, both in `Users` and in `UserLocations` you'd key children on UID.

Comment: Ok, I'll follow that advice. Thanks again!

Comment: Would it be possible to make a query to obtain only the latitude and save it on a local variable. Do the same with longitude and after that create a class named LOCATION where I store those values in a way that makes sense to me, to send them again to Firebase organized as longitude and latitude (No Geohash)? If so, how can I query for just the latitude, or the longitude?

Comment: Yup, that all sounds feasible. I'd actually just write the additional data straight under each user's node under `/Users` and do that at the same time you create the other user data.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I don't know how to query to obtain just the latitude or longitude? You've been very helpful, I appreciate it!

Comment: How did you write them into Firebase in the first place? That would be the best place to now duplicate them under `/Users` too.

Comment: mUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location");   geoFire =new GeoFire(mUser);